# Whats the difference between a Pokemon Trainer and a Pokemon Hunter?

Tags: pokemon

Whats the difference between a Pokemon Trainer and a Pokemon Hunter?

What makes a pokemon trainer not a pokemon Hunter?

Comment: Id like specifics please like is it because pokemon hunters are similar to dragon hunters in how to train your dragon except they sell pokemons cut up body parts

Comment: There are a couple of pokemon Hunters in the anime and comics. The major difference between them and a Pokémon trainer is that a Pokémon Hunter use his gadgets and poison to trap the Pokémon before pokeball'ing them rather than beating them in a battle; https://pokemon.fandom.com/wiki/Pokémon_hunter

Comment: @Valorum Shouldn't that be an answer?

Comment: @F1Krazy - I've not seen the episode/s in which they appear. I will leave it for someone who is more knowledgeable about the show than I.

Answer (score 1):

From the (admittedly very few) examples seen in the anime, hunters use traps, poisons/sedatives and various gadgets to catch and pokeball various Pokémon, rather than defeating them in battle like trainers do. Some just trap and sell the Pokémon, while others are also trainers.

Their behaviour is seen as unethical/unsporting.

Some, like J, and also the hunter who makes an appearance in the Kalos quest arc of the series, cross the line into illegal behaviour, trapping/stealing Pokémon belonging to others as well as wild Pokémon (e.g. J tying up trainers using her Ariados and using a weird gun to turn their Pokémon into statues so she can capture and later sell them in Diamond & Pearl Ep20, or the unnamed hunter trapping Beatrice's Bidoof in a cage he manages to chew through to escape and later Bonnie's Dedenne in a shock trap/electrified cage in Ep15 of XY Kalos Quest)

An argument can be made that Team Rocket act as Pokémon hunters too.

Comment: What examples are there and what methods do they use (and in which episodes/comics)?